# pass the value null when datetime is not filled by user

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I create a function. Where date can be selected by the user . And when the user not select the date i want to pass null .

```
 public DataSet  GetInvoicebyPaging(int pageIndex, int pageSize, Int32 clientId, DateTime  startDate, DateTime  endDate, string invoiceNumber, ref int totalInvoice)
{
 // doing something here 
}
```

And this is the code part where i am calling the function

```
_orderDAC.GetInvoicebyPaging(pageIndex, grdInvoice.PageSize, clientid, Convert.ToDateTime(txtFirstDate.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToDateTime(txtLastDate.Text.Trim()), txtInvoiceNumber.Text.Trim(), ref invoicecount);
```

Sometime the user cant fill the `txtFirstDate.Text` but i am converting Convert.TodateTime() so how can i fix this because when user not fill the datetime it give me exception. So how can i handle this .

Comment: make datetime nullable.. and also check if value is null

Comment: if value is null then how can i send the value i am geting exception there. because when user not fill any thing on textbox how this will convert.TodateTime()

Comment: sending value to DAC function GetInvoicebyPaging() where two value is DateTime  startDate, DateTime  endDate,

Comment: @zaki  or i need to use DateTime.Tryparse() if this how can i use DateTime.Tryparse() in my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your method to:

```
public DataSet GetInvoicebyPaging(int pageIndex, int pageSize, Int32 clientId, DateTime?  startDate, DateTime  endDate, string invoiceNumber, ref int totalInvoice)
{
    // doing something here 
}
```

And when you parse the user data you can do:

```
DateTime? start = null;
DateTime possibleStartValue;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTextBox.Text) && DateTime.TryParse(txtTextBox.Text, out possibleStartValue))
{
    start = possibleStartValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nullable date time variable as follows

```
DateTime? value = null;
```

and pass as a parameter

In your function you can use like `DateTime? value` as parameter

So you will have to do the following step

```
 DateTime? startDate=txtFirstDate.Text.Trim()==""?null:Convert.ToDateTime(txtFirstDate.Text.Trim());
```

change your function argument so that it can take null value as above.

Answer (score 0):

For any dates you want to be able to accept as null, like `DateTime startDate` you need to make them nullable like `DateTime? startDate`

And then before you call `GetInvoicebyPaging` try and sort out the datetimes.

```
DateTime startDate;
var correctStart = DateTime.TryParse(txtFirstDate.Text.Trim(), out startDate);
```

And then pass the parameter like

```
_orderDAC.GetInvoicebyPaging(pageIndex, grdInvoice.PageSize, 
clientid, (correctStart ? startDate : null), etc
```

And you may have to check if `txtFirstDate.Text` is null as well.
After declaring `startDate` above you can do:

```
var dateString = txtFirstDate.Text ?? "";
```

And pass `dateString.Trim()` into the `DateTime.TryParse`